# Array collection of many types C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to add Object as many type. I have search for this particular problem but I can't find any help on this scenario. Suppose I have a button click event that have many types, which are define below

```
  object[] InvokeParam = null;
    private void btnCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string t = "";
        int t1 = 0;
        float t2 = 0.2;
        InvokeParam = new object[3];
        string type = RecognizeType(t.GetType(),0);
        string type1 = RecognizeType(t1.GetType(), 1);
        string type2 = RecognizeType(t2.GetType(), 2);
    }
```

and RecognizeType function is

```
 private string RecognizeType(Type type,int Index)
    { 
        string typename = "";

        if (type.Equals(typeof(string)))
        {
            //InvokeParam[Index] = type as string;
            typename = "String";
        }
        else if (type.Equals(typeof(int)))
        {
            typename = "Int";
        }
        else if (type.Equals(typeof(double)))
        {
            typename = "Double";
        }
        else if (type.Equals(typeof(Single)))
        {
            typename = "Single";
        }
        else if (type.Equals(typeof(float)))
        {

            typename = "Float";
        }
        else if (type.Equals(typeof(decimal)))
        {
            typename = "Decimal";
        }
        else
        {
            typename = "Another Type";
        }

        return typename;
    }
```

I want every object in array as particular Type. If 1st one is of type string then it can make that index of object as string, so whenever any value enter by user it throws exception when another value other than string is entered.

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question and what you want to happen. I assume you should be using dynamic instead of object

Comment: I want to make multiple type object, reason behind this is every time i want to invoke all method on run time, i am working on their parameters type, since they contain many type , that's why i want array collection of many type

Comment: "Array collection of many types": Is there no one else in here thinking about anonymous types? Dont know if this fits your destinated goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly - you wish to set each value in the array with an initial type and then subsequently only allow that type at that position.

I think this problem can be solved with a simple class:

```
public class TypeMapper
{
    public readonly Type Type;
    object _value;
    public object Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            // If Type is null, any type is permissable. 
            // Else check that the input value's type matches Type.
            if (Type == null || value.GetType().Equals(Type))
                _value = value;
            else
                throw new Exception("Invalid type.");
        }
    }

    static Dictionary<string, Type> _types = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
    {
        { "string", typeof(string) },
        { "int", typeof(int) },
        { "double", typeof(double) },
    };

    public TypeMapper(string type)
    {
        // If 'type' is not described in _types then 'Type' is null
        // - any type is permissable.
        _types.TryGetValue(type, out Type);
    }
}
```

You can then use this class as follows:

```
object[] InvokeParam = new TypeMapper[2];
InvokeParam[0] = new TypeMapper("string");
(InvokeParam[0] as TypeMapper).Value = "Hello World"; // Ok
(InvokeParam[0] as TypeMapper).Value = 123; // Throws exception.
InvokeParam[1] = new TypeMapper("double");
(InvokeParam[1] as TypeMapper).Value = 123.456; // Ok
(InvokeParam[1] as TypeMapper).Value = false; // Throws exception.
```

Comment: acceptable answer. I am also trying like

InvokeParam[Index] = InvokeParam[Index] as int;

why doesn't work?

Comment: Try `InvokeParam[Index1].Value = InvokeParam[Index2].Value;`